# Connecting a database from an internet server

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb, oledbconnection

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                             Data Source= \\testadev.000webhostapp.com \ Database3.accdb";
        connection.Open();    
        connection.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex);
     }
}
```

I'm getting this **error**

[image]

I don't know if the ConnectionString is well used, probably that's the problem.
  The database is made in Acces 2016 without any password .
  Please, can you tell me where is the problem ?

Comment: What's with the spaces? I'm pretty sure it should at least be `Data Source=\\host\filename`, aside from anything else you might have to specify in the connection string. (Also, it sounds like a truly massively bad idea to open an Access database from a network share, let alone the internet -- at least *consider* an SQL Express instance as a backend. But that's another story...)

Comment: Is the file on a remote server? I think the provider should be `16.0` for Access 2016, not 12 as I think that's for Access 2007.
Also, maybe make sure you remove the spaces.

Comment: I think it's a remote server . I created it with a free hosting site (https://ro.000webhost.com/)  and with or without these spaces i'm getting the same error

Comment: Are you sure it offers a CIF? as in \\hostname\folder\file ? and not web/ftp? and that the account you are using has access to that (that seems less likely)

Comment: Have you verified the file path.  It is telling you file not found.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure because I do not know what CIF means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Accessing datafile via HTTP is not supported.**

If you want connect do datafile of Access, you need to do it via local file or network file. The network file can be accessed through UNC path.

Comment: UNC is limited to HTTP?

Comment: The problem is not UNC but requirements of accesing the datafile (i.e. partial file lock). And they can not be met with HTTP protocol.

Comment: There you can see all details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc227007.aspx

Comment: Ok,so I have to end up with Microsoft  Access. What other software (for creating databases) do you recommend me ? I want to create databases for  remote network accessing!

Comment: There si huge difference in "network accessing" in term of "local network" and "internet". In general it's not good idea to open your database to the internet. The best practice is to have some application server and the client is communication with application server via API (rest/rpc/...).

If this is not an option, use some "database servers". However event with application server you want something like "full" database server. My best recommendation is PostreSQL and Microsof SQL Server (express edition is for free).